# how to add additional label on x-axis on the rightmost in matlab figure?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the tick label set for the x-axis already and I also have the label set for the x-axis too. I am seeking a way to put an additional x label to the rightmost of the figure next to the x tick labels, is there any way to do so? Thanks

just like the following figure, the x ticks was added automatically and x label was added by the command xlabel. But I want to add one additional label "add'l" (red) in the figure. But I have many plots and/or subplots and the axes might be different, so I need to add that label with problem instead of manually.

[image: demo]

Comment: Can you add a figure examplifying what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a `uicontrol` that will be carefully placed in the relevant area.

```
   uicontrol('style','text',....);
```

If your UI is resizable, be sure to have the same units, i.e. if the text units are `Normalized`, then the axes units should be `Normalized` as well.

Comment: thx, so if there any way to make it work automatically? I have so many figures with different axis and size to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example on the MATPLOTLIB gallery page: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/alignment_test.html

It shows adding all kinds of different text to the axis.
[image]

Comment: thx, but I am looking for the solution in matlab, that example seems for python?

Comment: My fault, I thought the question was on matplotlib which is a Python library trying to duplicate Matlab. Perhaps it works in Matlab just the same?